# Copy ASM data to C++ variable

Tags: visual-c++, assembly

I'm trying to store the values (int) of `EBP+8`and `EBP+12` in two C++ variables. This is my code:

```
int a;
int b;

__asm {
    MOV &a, [EBP+12]
    MOV &b, [EBP+8]
}
```

But this is throwing some syntax errors. Which is the proper way to achieve this?

Comment: You can't `MOV` directly from memory to memory. Also, I'm not quite sure why you added those `&`s (?).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Well, `MOV` wants a memory address, right? Using `MOV a` will just put the value of `a` (probably `0`). So, how can I achieve this?

Comment: `mov eax,[ebp+12]` / `mov [a],eax`

Comment: Thanks for your help! I solved this yesterday but SO was offline. +1!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't remember that, as Michael said, I can't `MOV` directly from memory to memory. So I solved this by doing:

```
MOV EAX, [EBP+12]
MOV a, EAX
```